# How to add images to VStack when user presses a button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to make a simple app using SwiftUI where the user press the button, an image is added to the top of the VStack. How do I do that?

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried in order to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of the images name in an array. Define that array as a `@State` so it is redrawn every time it changes and make your button action insert at position 0 of that array the desired image name. In my example below you can see it in action in a playground (I'm using system images and I'm storing the names of the images as string).

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct TestView: View {

    @State var imageArray:[String] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Add Image"){
                self.addNewImage()
            }
            List(self.imageArray, id: \.self){ imageName in
                Image(systemName: imageName)
            }
        }
    }

    func addNewImage(){
        let randomImage = ["flame", "bolt", "hare", "ant"].randomElement()
        self.imageArray.insert(randomImage ?? "heart", at: 0)
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(TestView())´´´
```